# Difficulty in choosing correct answer among the options.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, compactness, connectedness, cantor-set

> 1) The Cantor set, a subset of the real numbers:
>
> A. is not compact.
>
> B. is not contained in an interval.
>
> C. does not contain a non-trivial interval.
>
> D. does not have uncountably many elements.

The facts about Cantor set assures me that options A, B are not correct. Also I know that Cantor set cannot contain any interval of non-zero length and it contains uncountably infinite no of points.

Option D and option C are confusing me. I think option C is correct but I am not sure.

Also I am not able to figure out the difference between uncountably many elements and uncountably infinite elements.

> 2) Let $F$ be a real valued function of real numbers such that $F(x)= \sin x, S = F \text{inverse of} {(-0.5,0.5)}$. Then $S$ is:
>
> I) a connected set.
>
> II) finite union of disjoint open intervals.
>
> III) a closed set.
>
> IV) an infinite union of disjoint open intervals.

I guess the set $S$ is $(-30,30)$ if I am not wrong.
Also every interval of real numbers is connected. So correct option is I).

I request to correct me and explain what's wrong with my calculation.

Comment: You don't have the correct set for problem 2. Think about what the inverse image of $(-0.5,0.5)$ under $\sin x$ would look like: it consists of all $x$-values for points on the graph of $\sin x$ whose $y$-values are within $(-0.5,0.5)$.

Comment: pretty sure uncountably many means uncountably infinite here.

Comment: @frank000: Not just here, but anywhere: an uncountable set is necessarily infinite. The expression *uncountably infinite* is redundant.

Comment: I guess the idea behind the problem 2 would have become clear enough if I just have visualized the graph of sine function. Thanks for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 1):

> (2)

$F^{-1}(S)\cap[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}]=(-{\pi\over6},{\pi\over6})$. As $F(x+2\pi)=F(x),$
$$
F^{-1}(x)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}\left(2\pi n+(-{\pi\over6},{\pi\over6})\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(2\pi n-{\pi\over6},2\pi n+{\pi\over6})
$$
So the correct choice is $(IV)$.

> (1)

An uncountable set is never finite. So $D$ is wrong. Trivial interval is either $\varnothing$ or a singleton set. Any other interval is non-trivial. So $C$ is correct.

Comment: I don't see you reasoning for (1)D. It is a standard fact that the Cantor set is compact, uncountable and a subset of $[0,1]$, which rules out A,B,D. That C is true requires an argument, but here we just need to eliminate the other answers. The OP never said the Cantor set was finite?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I didn't give a reasoning, the OP was confused about the term 'uncountably many', I just tried to clarify that. OP knows that Cantor set is uncoutable.

Comment: @jack's wasted life. I appreciate the simplicity of your answer. Visualizing the graph gives quick idea of problem 2.